# empty form field is still being submitted when using angular form validation

Tags: angularjs

The validation is being highlighted correctly, but when I click submit button, even with empty form field, the form is still being submitted (and nick value is undefined)

I tried adding `novalidate` to the form -- but that didn't help.

```
    <form class="nick" ng-submit="joinChat()">
        <input type="text" required name="nick" ng-model="nick" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="10">
        <button>Join</button>
    </form>
```

I'm trying to follow this guide here:
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

The `joinChat()` function doesn't do any validation itself. As its my understanding this shouldn't be necessary when using Angular form validation.

```
    $scope.joinChat = function(){
        socket.emit('chat:join', { nick: $scope.nick });
    };
```

Comment: Hii.. If i give `action=" "` in the form, angularjs validation is not working.. 
Do u know any solution for this ??

Comment: no need for `action` if you're using `ng-submit`

Comment: Hii @chovy... thnx for ur answer... but i've a new problem again... its working fine if i remove `action=" "` but the form is not being submitted... what's the problem ???

Answer (score 3):

Invalid input does not prevent angular form submission, instead try this:

```
<form class="nick" novalidate ng-submit="joinChat()" name="myform">
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" name="nick" ng-model="nick" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="10">
    <button ng-disabled="myform.$invalid">Join</button>
</form>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2336/)

Comment: what does `novalidate` on the form do?

Comment: it prevents default browser validation and lets angular handle validation

Comment: ok, also i had `<input name=nick ng-model=user.nick>` but I get [Object object] as the value. I changed `name` to `user.nick` but I don't know if that's right or if its even needed.

Comment: make fiddle please and i'll take a look at it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/hfS4e/ -- i just don't know what `name` attribute on the input field should be.

Comment: input does not need name attribute at all. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2336/

Comment: Thanks. I also notice that if you just hit enter in the field, then the form submits with undefined data. Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: no, it does not submit undefined data. check my fiddle, focus on text input and press enter, if the field is invalid, nothing will happen because pressing enter causes submit button to submit form, but submit button is disabled and that's why nothing happens

Comment: Hii @karaxuna... i don't want to disable the button, coz am showing the errors when button is clicked.. It's working fine until i give `action=" "` in the form.. If i give `action=" "` in the form, angularjs validation is not working.. Do u know any solution for this ??